# Boot from Recovery partition in Sony Vaio Laptop with no imagex

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio

I have visited more and more pages in internet and read lots of solutions but no one solved my problem.
I have my 10 GB win7 recovery partition in my Hard Disk but when I press the F10 button it was not booted from this partition (I use this method to recover my laptop several times recently).
So How can I boot from my recovery partition?

I copied the partition into a flash drive and tried to boot from usb but it does not take effect.

I think if there is a way to recover the F10 button functionality, I can recover my laptop.

Comment: Are you pressing F10 on it's own? On many Sony models, holding alt + F10 at boot will start the factory restore process

Comment: have you tried other buttons? https://superuser.com/questions/952322/recovery-partition-wont-boot-sony-vaio-windows-10