# recovery partition won't boot - sony vaio windows 10

Tags: boot, partitioning, sony-vaio

I  have a recovery partition that i used many times before using the vaio rescue system. recently though i have installed windows 10 over the win7 that came with the machine and it was a clean install, so now i think i lost the bios options that sony made, i can't recover or boot into the recovery partition.

i have tried everything, "assist" button, f10, f8, f12. nothing seems to work. but i still can see my recovery partition intact using diskpart. i tried to activate it and then try to boot but it didn't work and i got this error.

```
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.
The ACTIVE command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
```

is there any way i can access this partition and boot from it? using it to make a bootable image disk maybe? or anything else to solve the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before with my HP-Probook 4500. When I installed Windows 8 and wanted to go back to Windows 7 Pro, the same error appeared, so I used a bootable flash drive with Windows 7 to format the C drive, only to get an HDD. I hit the <kbd>F11</kbd> key and it worked.